# Verifying signed message in Solidity. ECDSA: invalid signature length

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, ecdsa

I am trying to verify a signed message using Solidity. For testing, the signed message is created using ethers.js. I am unable to verify the signed message because Solidity returns an "ECDSA: invalid signature length" error. I am using the latest (v4.8.0) version of OpenZeppelin ECDSA.

Generating signed message with ethers.js:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const owner = 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266;

const privateKey = ''; //redacted

const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey); //signer.address == owner

const amount = 2
const nonce = 1

// Test single sign
var message1 = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
  ["address","uint256","uint256"],
  [ signer.address, amount, nonce ]
);

message1 = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["bytes"], [message1]);
const signature1 = signer.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(message1));
console.log('Verify hash: ', message1);
console.log('Verify signature: ', signature1);
```

and that gives the following output:

```
Verify hash:  0x3090b10f01734400d183c56d240b4ea489b611d6fd59794c35cb327342517397
Verify signature:  Promise {
  '0xc7f625700fd30bb3d48191094345b853d9db52fbeb45f416c31b959edb7638032b9b975007bc2595c12a319a9d6a3eb926420101aaeddc2a34800aa4ff4cdf6c1c'
}
```

Then my solidity contract is the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/Vm.sol";
import {ECDSA} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract TestContract is Test {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    function testSignature() public {
        checkValidity('0xc7f625700fd30bb3d48191094345b853d9db52fbeb45f416c31b959edb7638032b9b975007bc2595c12a319a9d6a3eb926420101aaeddc2a34800aa4ff4cdf6c1c');
    }
    
    function checkValidity(bytes memory signature)
        public
        view
    {
        address owner = 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266;
        uint256 amount = 2;
        uint256 nonce = 1;

        address signature_recover = ECDSA.recover(
            ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(owner, amount, nonce))
            ),
            signature
        );
        console.log(signature_recover);
    }
}
```

Using the signature generated by ethers.js. This solidity contract returns the error `"ECDSA: invalid signature length"`.

Why is the signature length generated by ethers.js invalid? How can I generate a valid signature that can be validated by solidity?

Answer (score 1):

I think the message you are signing is wrong[image]

This is from openzeppelin ecdsa.sol , As you can see a string ""\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" is prefixed along with the hash but in your ether.js code you are not including this prefix string .

A better way to generate the message to sign would be to call the toEthSignedMessageHas function of ecdsa.sol and pass in message1(hash of the message in your example) and to sign the returning hash (this would include the prefix too)

Hope it is clear

Comment: The signer.SignMessage function includes the Ethereum Signed Message prefix. The following is from the ethers.js docs:

**signer.signMessage( message ) ⇒ Promise< string< RawSignature > >**

This returns a Promise which resolves to the Raw Signature of message.

A signed message is prefixd with "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" and the length of the message, using the hashMessage method, so that it is EIP-191 compliant. If recovering the address in Solidity, this prefix will be required to create a matching hash.